# ESP32_ARDUINO_IDE

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide

I am working with esp32. When i'm trying to run the code the error GDB executable "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe" was not found. Please configure "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath" or "cortex-debug.gdbPath" correctly." pop up. How to fix this?

Reinstalled arduino ide

Answer (score 0):

I receive this message when I try and run the debugger (which I do not have).

If you are just trying to run your code, use the button to the left to upload.